# There is a bug with Oracle 11g's ALL_TABLES table lookup

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I ran the below query on Oracle 11g.

```
SELECT  
    T.TABLE_NAME,               
    T.TABLESPACE_NAME, 
    T.CACHE,                    
FROM ALL_TABLES T
```

Then, there was a space in front of the Y or N value of the Cache property, which caused an error in my code.

Even if I check with Dbeaver or JDBC ResultSet, the blank is included.
Was this an intentional addition of spaces in Oracle? Or is it a bug?
First, I solved it by using trim().

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CACHE` column's datatype is `VARCHAR2(5)`. Documentation says that it contains `Y` or `N` (depending on whether table is to be cached in the buffer cache or not). So, why didn't Oracle declare it as `CHAR(1)`? It would do, right?

However, if you check `ALL_TABLES` source query, you'll notice that the `CACHE` column looks like this:

```
LPAD (DECODE (BITAND (t.flags, 8), 8, 'Y', 'N'), 5),
```

Oracle decided to left pad it to `5` characters in length (with spaces) (although the last parameter isn't specified, its default value is a single blank):

```
SQL> select lpad('Y', 5) cache from dual;

CACHE
-----
    Y

SQL>
```

So, yes - Oracle did that intentionally, but I wouldn't know *why*.

Comment: Thanks to this, the question was resolved. Thank you.

Comment: @Elvis - if that is so, please mark the “correct answer” as such.